# DNN SQL installation error

Tags: sql-server, dotnetnuke

I'm having a syntax issue with the SQL queries to create the tables for a DNN module. I've double checked my code and can't seem to find the issue. However, the DNN installation keeps saying there is an incorrect syntax near 'FK_bank_statement_day_name_table'. I've cross-checked it thoroughly but can't seem to figure

```
ALTER TABLE {databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}bank_statement_day]
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_bank_statement_day_name_table] FOREIGN 
KEY([file_name]) 
REFERENCES {databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}name_table] ([file_name])


ALTER TABLE {databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}bank_statement_day] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_bank_statement_day_name_table]
```

Comment: Your code looks ok [demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b414d6c3daeb0a92a54417c3512e045a) how `{objectQualifier}` are replaced with actual values?

Comment: yes i did. i replaced dbo.something with the objectQualifier thing that is supposed to be done for DNN.

Answer (score 1):

You likely are running into problems with DNN because you're missing the GO statements. Try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE {databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}bank_statement_day]
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_bank_statement_day_name_table] FOREIGN 
KEY([file_name]) 
REFERENCES {databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}name_table] ([file_name])
GO

ALTER TABLE {databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}bank_statement_day] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_bank_statement_day_name_table]
GO
```